# How do I call a module method in rspec, with the current module set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, module

So I have the following module for handling the fetching of and saving of tweets. This is all done on a thread, I am interested in testing two methods with in this module: `fetch_tweets` and `save_tweets`

For `fetch_tweets`, I want to validate that the `save_tweets` method is called. I don't care what it returns.

For the `save_tweets`, I want to test that a tweet is actually saved.

So with that in mind, lets look at some code.

**Twitter::TwitterHandler** - This lives in `lib/twitter/twitter_handler.rb`

```
module Twitter
  module TwitterHandler

    def handle_tweets(twitter_client_object)
      Thread.new do
        begin
          twitter_lock(twitter_client_object)
        ensure
          ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
        end
      end
    end

    def twitter_lock(twitter_client_object)
      TwitterTweet.with_advisory_lock('aisis-writer-tweets', 0) do
        fetch_tweets(twitter_client_object)
      end
    end

    def fetch_tweets(twitter_client_object)
      Rails.cache.fetch([:aisis_twitter_feed, Time.now.to_i/60/5], expires_in: 1.minute){
        twitter_client.user_timeline(user_id: '252157965', count: 100).map(&:as_json).select{ |h| h["text"].match(/aisiswriter/i) }.take(10).each do |tweet|
          save_tweets(tweet['id_str'], tweet['text'], tweet['created_at'])
        end
      }
    end

    def save_tweets(id, text, created_at)
      tweet = TwitterTweet.find_or_initialize_by(id: id)
      tweet.text = text
      tweet.created_at = created_at
      tweet.save
    end

  end
end
```

**twitter_handler_spec.rb** - This lives in spec/twitter/twitter_handler_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
require_relative '../../lib/twitter/twitter_handler'

describe 'TwitterHandler' do

  context "fetch tweets method" do
    it "should fetch some tweets" do
      t = Time.parse("01/01/2010 10:00")
      Time.should_receive(:now).and_return(t)
      expect(fetch_tweets(twitter_client)).to receive(:save_tweets).with('342', 'Something', t).and_return nil
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `bin/rspec spec/twitter/twitter_handler_spec.rb` I get:

```
Failures:

  1) TwitterHandler fetch tweets method should fetch some tweets
     Failure/Error: expect(fetch_tweets(twitter_client)).to receive(:save_tweets).with('342', 'Something', t).and_return nil
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `fetch_tweets' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::TwitterHandler::FetchTweetsMethod:0x007ff1c724e300>
     # ./spec/twitter/twitter_handler_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How do I fix this, so I can call this method and any other method in this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call instance methods of a module. You must `include` or `extend` the module and then call the methods on the object which included or extended the module. The error you are getting from rspec is because you're calling `fetch_tweets` from within your example, but `fetch_tweets` is not defined within the example.

Once you solve the problem of invoking `fetch_tweets`, then you've got to deal with the fact that your `expect(fetch_tweets(...))` expectation is saying that the object returned by `fetch_tweets` is going to receive a method call of `:save_tweets`, which is not what you want. Per your description, you want to set an expectation that whatever object included or extended `TwitterHandler` will receive `save_tweets` and *then* you want to call `fetch_tweets`.

If this isn't clear, I suggest you read up on Ruby module methods and then read up on RSpec.